# How to support global variable in Grafana common to all dashboards?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I am using a custom formula in a variable that I want to use across multiple dashboards. Is there a way to make global variable in grafana?

Comment: please tag me, if this gets answered, as interested in this also. tks

Comment: Or maybe, in my case anyhow, there is a way to have a panel shared accross multiple dashboards, or maybe that is the same thing..

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like Grafana supports this, as of version 9.

See https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/1959, from 2015, and some duplicates:

- https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/5504
- https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/12095
- https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/16797

You can subscribe to an issue to be notified of any updates.

The only global variables available for now are the built-in ones listed here -

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/variables/variable-types/global-variables/